# Creating a Block with Number of Fixed Input Elements GNU RADIO

Tags: python, gnuradio

I was able to create a block that has an input quantity other than output, in case the output will always have 6 more elements. But now I'm having trouble making the block always get length X complex samples. For example my block will always have a fixed input amount and will not be the default of 4096 samples

```
import numpy
from gnuradio import gr
import math
import numpy as np

class codificador_wavelet(gr.basic_block):
    """
     docstring for block codificador_wavelet
   """
   def __init__(self,taxa):
       gr.basic_block.__init__(self,
          name="codificador_wavelet",
          in_sig=[numpy.complex64],
          out_sig=[numpy.complex64])
       self.taxa=taxa
       self.mg=8
   def forecast(self, noutput_items, ninput_items_required):
       n = noutput_items-6 
       ninput_items_required[0] = 1 if (n<=0) else n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is quite a full answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

If the block always wants a known constant input size, you might try accepting vector inputs using the stream to vector block like what's shown in the [core concepts tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/TutorialsCoreConcepts#Items). To hide this from the user, you can use a [hierarchical block](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/GNURadioCompanion#Hierarchical_Blocks) containing the stream to vector block and the block that you're creating.